# Shorthand if madness, is it possible to rewrite even smarter?

Tags: php, conditional-operator, null-coalescing-operator

I have this structure (currently working on PHP 7.4)

```
/** @var bool $shouldBeEmpty */
/** @var array $array */
if ($shouldBeEmpty) {
    $array = [];
} else {
    $array = $data['some_data'] ?? [];
}
```

It could be rewritten in one line like this

```
$array = $shouldBeEmpty ? [] : $data['some_data'] ?? [];
```

Question is - is this possible to get rid of one `[]` and do the same with only one `[]`.

Assigning `[]` to variable or replacing one with `array()` won't be the case.

Is there only option that $shouldBeEmpty should be empty/non-empty array so I could reuse it? Boolean won't work in any case?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, example is quite terrible, but in real class it looks a bit better.

Also, this code is executed in OOP, of course, and it will make sense to use example from a class.

As well as what I realised, that I could simply use preseted value from the class property, so I don't have to change it if I don't need to. So, here is the example, I am quite happy with.

```
class MyClass
{
  protected $collectedData = [];

  public function __construct($data)
  {
    if (!$data['shouldBeEmpty']) {
      $this->collectedData = $data['some_data'] ?? [];
    }
  }
}
```